# Why Does equipotential surfaces gets father apart in the regions of weak electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, potential-energy, voltage

If we consider a charge in space then we can draw infinite number of spheres (taking the distance between the spheres equal) around the charge and these spheres act as equipotential surfaces. Now, As the distance of all points on the sphere are same from the charge then why does equipotential surface gets farther apart when electric field decreases??i mean my questions is what is the problem with taking the distance between equipotential surface equal??

Comment: How can equipotential surfaces get “farther apart” when there are an infinite number of them nested infinitely close together?

Comment: When did i say they are infinitely close…i said at equal distances